# How to assign a context to a webworker in nodejs

Tags: node.js, web-worker

I have a webworker running on nodejs. I want to set the 'context' of the webworker.

i.e. I want to make a value available to the webworker.

From: 
https://www.npmjs.org/package/webworker-threads

> .eval( program [, cb])
>
> thread.eval( program [, cb]) converts program.toString() and eval()s
>   it in the thread's global context, and (if provided) returns the
>   completion value to cb(err, completionValue).

how do I set the "thread's global context".

Comment: What do you mean by `set` the global context? Did you want to bind it to your own context?

Comment: Yes, or at least be able to set an initial value in the threads context. ... I suspect this is what I need https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads/blob/master/examples/ex06_jason.md